# How do I add another column in r using mutate and if else statements?

Tags: r

I have a large csv file that I have been trying to edit.  I have been trying to create a new column titled race.  There is currently a column called derived_race that has multiple races in it including White, Black or African American, Asian, joint, etc.  I need to get the derived_race category down to White, Black, and Other.  I have tried to use mutate to add another column, and the code that I used looked like this:

```
mutate(selected_public_2018_lar,Race = if (derived_race == 'White'){
print("White")
 } else if (derived_race == 'Black or African American'){
print("Black")
}else {
print("Other")
})
```

I keep getting an error that looks like this:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` can't be recycled to size 2316993.
ℹ Input `..1` is `selected_public_2018_lar`.
ℹ Input `..1` must be size 2316993 or 1, not 179666.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to create a column in a data.frame, we can either use `ifelse` or `case_when` as `if/else` is not vectorized and also the `print` is just for printing the values

```
library(dplyr)
selected_public_2018_lar <- selected_public_2018_lar %>%
       mutate(Race = case_when(derived_race == 'Black or African American' ~ 'Black',
          derived_race == 'White' ~ White', TRUE ~ "Other"))
```

---

Or another option is `ifelse`

```
selected_public_2018_lar %>%
    mutate(Race = ifelse(derived_race == 'Black or African American', 'Black', ifelse(derived_race == 'White', 'White', 'Other')))
```

---

Or with `recode`

```
selected_public_2018_lar %>%
    mutate(Race =  recode(`Black or African American` = 'Black',
                      'White' = 'White', .default = 'Other'))
```